# CodeIgniter db->query returning false on SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This particular application has been in use for over a year now, and uses several dozen models, and I am having trouble only with this one particular new function.

```
public function get_slides($promo = NULL) {

    $sql = "SELECT description as alt, image, link
    FROM " . CONFIG_DATABASE . ".slides
    WHERE active = '1' AND acct_no = '" . API_ACCT . "' ORDER BY priority ASC;";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    var_dump($sql);
    var_dump($query);

    return $query->result_array();

}
```

The results of this are:

```
string 'SELECT description as alt, image, link
        FROM web_config_development.slides
        WHERE active = '1' AND acct_no = '10001' ORDER BY priority ASC;' (length=143)
boolean false
```

Followed by:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object

The query works fine in MySQL Workbench.  In my searching for this issue I have come across docs referring to true/false responses on INSERT and DELETE, but not on SELECT.

This does not make any sense ... if you have any ideas, sharing them would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how the CodeIgniter query classes work, but perhaps the `;` at the end of the query string is not allowed?

Comment: are you sure your database helper is loaded ?

Comment: Never fails, ask the question on stack overflow, figure it out immediately.  It was table permissions.

Comment: Did you turn on CI's profiler $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE); to   the raw query ?

Comment: try this http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/138422/

Comment: @David You can add that as the answer to help people having the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was table permissions.  The application user was not added to the new table.

Comment: It seems case occurs when the query produces any type of error and `db_debug` is turned off. If other users have this problem, then you have an error in your query or a permission issue with the current user, something which would trigger an error. CodeIgniter simply returns `false` on the `$this->db->get()` function. Ensure `db_debug` is set to `true` in your `database.php` config file to have CodeIgniter display a useful error message for you.

Answer (score 1):

> if used **result_array()** then first will be checked number of rows in query

```
if($query->num_rows()>0){
   return $query->result_array();  
}else {
   return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe you are calling the wrong method to get the result.

Try this

```
return $query->result();
```

For more information about about Codeigniter active record go [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html/)

Comment: $query->result(); gives an object. 
$query->result_array(); gives an associative array.